# Adding a title attribute to category without affecting core

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My current setup includes having the category of each post.  But whenever I mouse over the category, it shows the default message of `Show all posts in [category]`.

I have looked around and have seen some pretty similar questions that require multiple lines of php code.  This surely cannot be that complicated.  Is there a way I can perhaps tweak the following to get it to do what I want?

```
<?php the_category(' '); ?>
```

This is the code that returns the above.  I am looking through the codex and found `category_description()` and `get_the_category()`.  I am kind of new to arrays and am having problems figuring them out.  I was kind of hoping that something like this would work:

```
<?php the_category('title=category_description()'); ?>
```

but it is not.  I know that is a pretty hilarious way of solving this to most of you but I am completely lost.  I just want the description of the category to be the title attribute.  Is there a simple way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

using get_the_category(); you can save all of the categories into a variable.
Ex:

```
$categories = get_the_categories();
```

There is however an optional parameter that you can pass; the category ID.
Ex:

```
$categories = get_the_categories(THE_CATEGORY_ID);
```

Whether you present a category ID or not you must run $categories through a loop.
Ex:

```
foreach($categories as $category){

}
```

Only then, will you be able to customize your title attribute without modifying the wordpress code.
Ex:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="'.YOUR_CUSTOM_TITLE.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a bit: `<?php foreach($categories as $category){echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="'.$category->category_description.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';} ?>`